# The target origin does not match the recipients window's origin

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, iframe

I am trying to post a message from a MVC website that I am hosting in an iframe in a Angular website but when using `window.postMessage` I get the above error. This is my code:

In MVC site (called via iframe):

```
// I need to tell Angular when something has changed here to update their menu
var data = { foo: 'bar' }
window.postMessage(data, 'http://localhost:4200/');
```

Angluar listening to message post:

```
renderer.listen('window', 'message', (event) => {
if (event.origin.startsWith('http://localhost')) {
     console.log(event.data) // should output: {foo: 'bar'}
   }
});
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this code, you are trying to post a message from the iframe to the iframe itself. The error about the target origin occurs because the recipient window's origin is actually the embedded app's one. Indeed, if you want to notify the parent window, dont refer to it as `window` but as `window.parent` (`window` being the MVC app's `window`):

```
window.parent.postMessage(data, 'http://localhost:4200/');
```